# Merge,Overlap the pictures and save to one file

Tags: c#, merge, image, overlap

I want to make a class in `C#` that provided for ServiceFacade to calling it.

Now I can get image from the other service. [For Example.](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=8439979.14831667,-644273.9207,14149114.9749834,3637577.9493&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800,600&imageSR=3857&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson) and [Example2](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Earthquakes/RecentEarthquakesRendered/MapServer/export?bbox=-179.439816158088%2C-175.044916158088%2C179.718316158088%2C184.113216158088&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=4326&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson)

***In that link you can see url of the map image.***

Then I have to get many of the map images (get many layer of map)

***The first image.***

[image: Image 1]

***The second image.***

[image]

**Question**

How to overlap the many of images to one image, then when have that one image how to save it to the local disk.

***The Result***

[image]

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to overlap them (not really sure what you mean by this), but you would first create a bitmap the size that you need inorder to hold all of the images in the layout that you want.

```
Bitmap final = new Bitmap(int x, int y);
```

then you would need to get the graphics device from that bitmap. You will be using this object to draw all of the other images onto the final image at the desired locations in the desired laying.

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(final))
{
   foreach (Image image in imageList)
   {
      g.DrawImage(image, point);  // point - location of where images top-left corner should be.
   }
}
```

Then when you are done, you would just call the Save function of the image to a string file location.

```
final.Save(location);
```

Comment: I have questions, if I have two images I have to call `g.DrawImage(image, point);` 2 times right? And what is `point` in `g.DrawImage(image, point);`

Comment: You will need to call g.DrawImage for each image that you wish to draw. And point is the location on the final Bitmap that you wish to start drawing the Bitmap from it's top-left corner. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx

Comment: Thanks I have test it by adding two of images, its runing fine but the result of image is not valid, it's doesn't overlap these two of images. It's only copy the last of image that I have added.

Comment: please defined what you mean by "overlap". Currently the last image is overlapping the previous ones, thus why you are only seeing the last one (you are drawing the last image on top of the previous image.)

Comment: I'm mistake, the picture doesn't transparented. Thank you very much now it's work! :D